# 301 Redirection no longer works

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I made a redirection with the following code in my htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteRule ^videos(/.*)?$ https://www.wemagicmusic.com/clips-wm/ [L,R=301,NC]
</IfModule>
```

It worked when I did it. But now, strangely enough, it doesn't work anymore. I don't understand what's not working.

Can you help me, please?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you on shared hosting and do you have access to Apache configuration files? Your host may have disabled directory overrides in the Apache config (look for `AllowOverride None` in a virtual host directive file).

Comment: Thank you @DavidCara. is done !